# integration of RFID with IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am looking for references or some tutorials that talk about integration of RFID with iOS .

or library that I can use on Xcode .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no RFIF reader in any iOS device at current time. Your only hope is that some third party accessory maker has a reader.

This would mean that the third party accessory maker will also have to supply the SDK and every reader will have there own specific SDK.

---

I found this RFID reader:http://www.icarte.ca/info110.shtml they might have there own SDK, which I could not find.

Comment: sorry one more question, I found this one http://www.icarte.ca/docs/SW10-0058-DS%20-%20iCarte%20420.pdf
does support objective-c ?

Comment: It does not say, but you could just e-mail them and ask.